# Get TextBox By Name - Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm facing the following pbm.

**Question :**

I would to know the method to call the .value of textboxes/comboboxes by a String.

**Example :**

```
If InputLibelle.Value <> Me!SubStockEdit!DSLibelle.Value Then
```

I want to compare the value of **ItemName TextBox** (Input + ItemName) and value of another Textbox in Subform Datasheet (SubStockEdit!DS + ItemName) multiple times.

**Code attempt :**

```
Dim TableColumnNames() As String
        TableColumnNames = Split("Poids, Dimension1, Dimension2,
                                  Dimension3, Description, Price", ",")
For Each ColumnName In TableColumnNames
     If  Me.Name("Input" & ColumnName).Value <> ???
Next
```

Anyone have idea how to call these objects ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be:

```
Dim TableColumnNames() As String

TableColumnNames = Split("Poids, Dimension1, Dimension2, Dimension3, Description, Price", ",")

For Each ColumnName In TableColumnNames
    If Me("Input" & ColumnName).Value <> Me!SubStockEdit("DS" & ColumnName).Value Then
        ' Do stuff.
    End If
Next
```

or perhaps this expanded syntax:

```
    If Me("Input" & ColumnName).Value <> Me!SubStockEdit.Form("DS" & ColumnName).Value Then
```

Answer (score 1):

Try one of this

```
Controls("Input" & ColumnName).Name
Controls("Input" & ColumnName).Value

Me!SubStockEdit!Form.Controls("Input" & ColumnName).Value

eval("Input" & ColumnName)
eval("Me!SubStockEdit!DSLibelle")
```

Comment: Thx aswell for your answer.